# Android - How to make a spinner that changes two values

Tags: java, android, download, spinner

How would I make a spinner that on select changes two values in an Async download task?  (The URL and filename)  I can only figure out how to change one value in the spinner, is it possible to change two in the same drop down list on select?  Do I need a submit button or can I have it start the download process just on select?  I think its possible but I've never worked with spinners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you make a function to take care of changing the values, and then simply make the spinner's onSelect listener call that function?

I don't have too much experience working with spinners myself either, but that's the first way I'd go about trying to do it...